# No overload for method '(Function Name)' takes '0' arguments

Tags: c#, overloading

while debugging i got this error : "No overload for method 'STUDENTCOURSEDETAILS_Load' takes '0' arguments"

The STUDENTCOURSEDETAILS is a Winform and STUDENTCOURSEDETAILS_Load is the OnLoad event for the form.i tried to call this event in another function and got the above said error.How can i call an Event in another function ? How  can I Pass parameter's while calling this Event ?I Don't Know what kind of Parameter's sholud I have to Pass. Need Help...

```
private void STUDENTCOURSEDETAILS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtregno.Enabled        = false;
            txtstudentname.Enabled  = false;
            txtcoursid.Enabled      = false;
            txtcoursname.Enabled    = false;
            dtpdoj.Enabled          = false;
            txtfee.Enabled          = false;
            txtdiscountper.Enabled  = false;
            txtnarration.Enabled    = false;
            btnSave.Text            = "&Add";

        }

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (btnSave.Text)
            {
                case "&Add":
                    txtregno.Enabled        = true;
                    txtstudentname.Enabled  = true;
                    txtcoursid.Enabled      = true;
                    txtcoursname.Enabled    = true;
                    dtpdoj.Enabled          = true;
                    txtfee.Enabled          = true;
                    txtdiscountper.Enabled  = true;
                    txtnarration.Enabled    = true;
                    btnSave.Text            = "&Save";
                    break;
                case "&Save":
                    if (validation())
                    {
                        if (MessageBox.Show("sure to save?", CPublic.messagename, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            selectstudentid();
                            cmd.Connection = CPublic.Comm_con;
                            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regno", txtregno.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentid", id);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentname", txtstudentname.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseid", txtcoursid.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@coursename", txtcoursname.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doj", dtpdoj.Value.ToString(CGeneral.ServeDateFmt));
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fee", txtfee.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount", txtdiscountper.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@narration", txtnarration.Text);
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.CommandText = "SP_INSERT_studentcoursedetails" + CPublic.g_firmcode;
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            MessageBox.Show("COURSE ADDED SUCCESSFULLY...", CPublic.messagename, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                            clearall();
                            btnSave.Enabled         = true;
                            btnSave.Text            = "&Add";
                            STUDENTCOURSEDETAILS_Load();
                         }
                    }
                            break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Move the code in `STUDENTCOURSEDETAILS_Load` to another method and invoke it both in `STUDENTCOURSEDETAILS_Load` and in `btnAdd_Click`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because of the line

```
btnSave.Text            = "&Add";
STUDENTCOURSEDETAILS_Load();
```

You should rather use

```
STUDENTCOURSEDETAILS_Load(null, null);
```

Obviously there can be further error which you may face at runtime.

Comment: Thanks @Nisarg Shah. Any way it's working fine and looking forward for that runtime error you specified. So what is the proper way to do this task ???

Comment: Please mention the error that you are getting. Because precise error will help me resolve your error

Comment: No overload for method 'STUDENTCOURSEDETAILS_Load' takes '0' arguments" This is what i was getting before  and not now .

Comment: Yeah that is what the solution is for. So now what else do you want?

Comment: You Have Mentioned that **"there can be further error which you may face at runtime"** So i was asking how can i avoid that runtime error?

Comment: That i have mentioned because i was not having your complete code. There is just a possibility. It is not for sure that you will get error. It is just tentative.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the method like this:

```
STUDENTCOURSEDETAILS_Load(null, null);
```